# Dataflow And Continuous Integration

Tags: continuous-integration, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to figure out a way to integrate continuously the process of dataflow jobs, starting with pushing code on github up to the end. This is, executing a job on dataflow. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi there - it might be an idea to post some code / details on what you've tried so far to help focus the question a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sparky! I'm not at that point yet, I'm trying to figure out an architecture first. My idea, so far, turns around, having a jenkins server pulling from github, to an artifact repo (Nexus for instance).. on the other hand develop an app that lauches those artifacts (jobs) into dataflow .. All this running in compute engine..
I'd like to know about different aproaches..

Comment: Building and invoking a Dataflow pipeline seems not different from building and invoking any other executable via continuous integration - it's just a Java (or Python) program. Do you anticipate any particular difficulties?

Comment: Actually not @jkff! The only thing  is that we need  to develop a tool to manage and launch the artifacts .. and I was hoping to find an alternative that doesn't require to do this!

Comment: You may want to follow https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/BEAM-551 which will ultimately allow to deploy a pipeline once and then launch it with different parameters.